# How to get a list of recently closed applications in Windows Xp?

Tags: windows-xp, productivity

How to get a list of recently closed applications in Windows Xp? like firefox has recently closed tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re-launch Recently Closed Programs and Folders with [ReOpen](http://www.favessoft.com/hotkeys.html)** (For Windows XP and later)

- Like FolderCache with additional List for Programs
- Default hotkey is Shift-Pause or click Middle Mouse Button on desktop
- Hotkey adjustable via Tray Menu
- Middle Mouse Button Click enable/disable via Tray Menu
- Background color adjustable on Glass enabled systems

[image]

> You just need to click the program or
>   folder path you want to re launch and
>   click the button at the top of the
>   application saying **Open Selected**
>   and click **Stack Selected** if you
>   want to make a shortcut here in this
>   application to lunch the folder or
>   program. Else you can delete the
>   program or folder from the list by
>   clicking the button saying **Delete
>   Selected**.

Of course, you don't have to open them, if you only want to look up the recently closed programs, they're listed in the bottom window, in the top right corner you can specify the amount of entries listed.

*ReOpen is freeware and portable (doesn't require to be installed).*